# Select data from multiple columns in the same row and populate drop-down list

Tags: sql, .net

I have three columns per row, phone1,  phone2, phone3, that I want to put in a single drop-down list per row. The drop-down list is being populated in a gridview through onrowcreated event. When I bind the drop-down list it specifies a single column, so I don't know how to specify all three columns. I'm thinking I can do this in the sql query but don't know how. Currently, with the sql query below, I get 3 phone number concatenated together for 1 entry. I want to get 3 separate and selectable entries in the dropdown list. I do not want to concatenate them together!

Gridview section:

```
                            <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPhone" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Visual Basic:

```
Protected Sub Gridview2_OnRowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then

        'Find the DropDownList in the Row
        Dim ddlPhone As DropDownList = CType(e.Row.FindControl("ddlPhone"), DropDownList)
        ddlPhone.DataSource = GetCrew("SELECT CONCAT(phone1, phone2, phone3) As Phone From Referee Where RefereeId = @RefereeId")
        ddlPhone.DataTextField = "Phone"
        ddlPhone.DataValueField = "Phone"
        ddlPhone.DataBind()

        'Add Default Item in the DropDownList
        'ddlPhone.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please select"))

        ''Select the Country of Customer in DropDownList
        'Dim country As String = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblCountry"), Label).Text
        'ddlPhone.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetCrew(query As String) As DataSet
    Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("assignConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
    Using con As New SqlConnection(conString)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@oid", Request.QueryString("oid")))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RefereeId", userIdlbl.Text))
        Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
            cmd.Connection = con
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd
            Using ds As New DataSet()
                sda.Fill(ds)
                Return ds
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking I can do this in the sql query but don't know how

You could, but you can also do it on the display side by binding to a projection from the source:

```
ddl.DataSource = new [] {row.phone1, row.phone2, row.phone3};
```

Comment: My ddl.datasource is the sql query so it's the datatextfield and the datavaluefield that can only accept one value maybe

Comment: @mlg74 Post what you're _currently_ doing and you'll get more specific answers. Essentially you'll need to concatenate the two as a drop down list only has one "value" per row.